# Maven unable to run specific test

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running test cases through maven. Using following commands :

**Getting Success** : `mvn test`

**Getting Failure** : `mvn -Dtest=LoginTest test`

The class name is LoginTest

Stacktrace :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
>   (default-test) on project Web: No tests were executed!  (Set
>   -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)  -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
>   (default-test) on project Web: No tests were executed!  ( Set
>   -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were
>   executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:579)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>           ... 20 more

Comment: Can you post the test class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe surefire is looking for a suffix of "Test" by default, not "test".  Either rename your class to end with "Test", or add "test" to your surefire configuration in your pom.xml like this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.class</include>
                        <include>**/*test.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks I got mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your question above, you wrote `mvn -Dtest=Logintest test`.  Maybe you typed it wrong?

Comment: Yes exactly. In that command, it should be LoginTest, T should be capital. thanks for hint.